# apply spacing between element and a border

Tags: css

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/apmxzzpa/)

html:

```
<span id="foo">foo</span>
```

css:

```
#foo{
    background: #f00;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

But the margin-top is applied over whole element. I want a space between red background and black border.

I've tried it with `:before` pseudo but with this I've to give width for the border and this is not good idea because the `#foo` element's width may vary.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? are you trying to put a space between the `<span>`'s border and its text content?

Comment: The border is attached to the span. Pretty sure you can't do that....

Comment: @MattD You're allowed to change the html markup (like wraping them and giving a empty span and applying border to that) so that the required style would be achieved. But what's that exactly not happening what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a padding and `background-clip: content-box;`

```css
#foo{
    background: #f00;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<span id="foo">Foo</span>
```

Of course, this limits other available padding things, but this answers the question.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: If you need to support IE7, you're going to have a difficult time. IE8+ supports pseudo-elements, so you could use :before (similar to other answers) but here's a working example (using 100% width for variable width): http://jsfiddle.net/mnydy03c/

Comment: I'm amazed with the behavior of pesudo. I'm getting full window width for that border what you have shown me (with my site).

Comment: And if I use background-clip then the padding in red div would be collapsed.

Comment: Be sure to set position: relative on the parent span.

Comment: Please check this demo with background-clip: http://jsfiddle.net/mnydy03c/1/ which is not able to have the padding.

Comment: And with the pseudo, I don't know why this is getting 100% width as full window width...

Answer (score 1):

I think You can try :before to ge
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/apmxzzpa/5/)

```
 span:before{ border-top: 5px solid #000;display:block;content:"";margin-top:-6px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use the following pseudo class to achieve this. You just need to alter the height and top value of :after to achieve the required border spacing. You will also need to change the margin-top of #foo, in case you want a larger top border.

```
#foo{
  background: #f00;
  display: inline-block;  
  padding-top: 10px;    
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#foo:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  top: -9px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5cstrzsx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript solution to this:

The idea is to wrap the `<span>` in a `<div>`. Get the `width` and `height` of the `span` element using JavaScript. Set the `width` of the `div` equal to the `width` of the `span`. Set the `height` of the `div` equal to the `height` of the `span` + `20` and finally, give the `span` element a `20px` `marginTop`.

Note that I've added `box-sizing: border-box` to `#border` so that it's `width` would be the same as the `#foo` element.

```js
var border = document.getElementById('border');
var span = document.getElementById('foo');

border.style.width = (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(span).width.slice(0, -2))) + 'px';
border.style.height = (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(span).height.slice(0, -2))) + 20 + 'px';
span.style.marginTop = '20px';
```

```css
#foo {
    position: relative;
    background: #f00;
    display: inline-block;
}
#border {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">
    <span id="foo">foo</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the easier solution by changing the markup like this:

```
<span class="content"><span class="border-top">&nbsp;</span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zwyaqmxz/)